# How can i execute a jar file and capture the output for use in my R script?

Tags: r, jar, text-mining, rjava, rweka

The jar file I am using has an output of a bunch of text files. I would like to use these files for text mining. Rather than execute the jar file separately and then use the output for my R script, I want my R script to initiate the jar execution as well. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured how to do this. I used the system() command like so

```
system ("java -jar tika-app-1.14.jar -t -i test.pdf")
```